# What setting controls how many files you can upload simultaneously using lightning:fileUpload?

Tags: fileupload

I want to use `<lightning:fileUpload/>` to upload multiple files in my lightning component. In the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation) for this component, it is said that:

> By default, you can upload up to 10 files simultaneously unless your Salesforce admin has changed that limit. The org limit for the number of files simultaneously uploaded is a maximum of 25 files and a minimum of 3 files.

What I need is to increase this limit from 10 to at least 15-20. But I was not able to find how as a Salesforce admin I can change this, is there a setting for this somewhere in the setup?

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to the support? Couldn't really find anything in the setup to do so.

Comment: @JayantDas I have opened a case and got final reply today, will post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have opened a case to Salesforce to clarify that about a week ago. Got final answer today - this limit can be changed by Salesforce and to do this you have to open a case. They will update the documentation to reflect this soon.